# Call a method when class loads in java

Tags: java, class, methods, load

I have an action in which I want to use one global kind of variables which will be set with a static values.i.e setting a year hash map like 1-Jan, 2-Feb and so on..

I want to know that is there any mechanism in which this logic will be called only once and then by all the methods, it will be used.

I know about constructor. but still any thing which will be executed once the class is loaded and later on can be used by other methods as and when required.

Thanks in adv...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put the initialization code in the `static` block. Example:

```
private static Map<Integer, Integer> yourMap;

static {
    yourMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    callTheStaticMethod();
}

public static void callTheStaticMethod() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your static method needs a return type.

Comment: @orien - Thanks. I missed to type it:)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. but will this work in struts action class ??

Comment: I haven't used `Struts`, but why not? It is still a class.

Answer (score 0):

You canu use Singleton Pattern.